# Grand Central Dispatch with Swift: Use of unresolved identifier GCD

Tags: swift, swift2, grand-central-dispatch, foundation

Recently I picked up the book *Swift High Performance* and tried one of the examples concerned with Apple's Grand Central Dispatch (GCD). I put the following code in a Playground file:

```
import Foundation
//import XCPlayground
//XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()

class SalesData {

    var revenue: [Int]
    var average: Int?

    init (revenue: [Int]) {
        self.revenue = revenue
    }

    func calculateAverage() {

        let queue = GCD.backgroundQueue()
        dispatch_async(queue) {

        var sum = 0
        for index in self.revenue.indices {
            sum += self.revenue[index]
        }

        self.average = sum / self.revenue.count
    }
}
```

*Excerpt From: “Swift High Performance.”*

However, as can be seen in the [attahced sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4RwL.png)
, XCode tells me that ther is a `Use of unresolved identifier GCD`. Any idea what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such class called `GCD`. If you want to get a background queue, you can use this `dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND.rawValue), 0)`

Comment: @Breek has your answer. With updates to swift you can now do `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)){ //code to run on background queue }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the book, they define a struct called `GCD` which provides that method. So you have to look in the book to get the rest of the code that you need for the example.

EDIT:

This is the `GCD` struct that the book provides:

```
struct GCD {
    static func backgroundQueue() -> dispatch_queue_t {
        return dispatch_get_global_queue (QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)
    }
}
```

It appears on the same page as the example posted in the question.

Comment: oh my, that's embarrassing... it's obviously too late for me :/. thank you very, very much for pointing me to something that should've been obvious.

Comment: @sbstnbelle It happens to all of us. Just about every programmer has had the experience of spending an hour (or a day, or more!) to figure out how to fix a problem that turned out to be trivial.

Comment: @Gain sure, we all went through this "valley of tears" at least once in our career. however, this one was one of the superfluous and embarrassing ones ;). so, thank you even more for your patient and kind help. I really appreciate it!